# problem with clicking on elements python selenium

Tags: python

```
users = driver.find_elements_by_name('value')
for users1 in users:
    users.click()
```

I get error:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'`

I want click in a loop all users with name='value'
[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toceu.jpg)

Comment: typo: looks like it should be `users1.click`

Comment: what some time when I am in check the element "element" disappears and reappears as if it closes the container, so it seems to me that when it does, I don't click on the elements anymore, do you know what to do in this case? @rv.kvetch